# multidimensionel cube: sum on filtered fact

Tags: mdx, cube

I have a fact_dueAnalysis table which contains all my customers outstanding. The table is built with a Date Reporting, so when I pick a specific Date Reporting date, I can see all customers outstanding for that specific day.

Now I want to let my users use a date hierarchy so they can select e.g. week 39 and get all outstanding for the LAST day of that week (I will always use the last date in the hierarchy my users have selected).

I have made the following script:

```
([Measures].[Due Amount],[Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].members) =
sum(generate(tail(
DESCENDANTS([Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week],, leaves),1),1
)
,[Measures].[Customer Due Amount]);
```

I am here trying to get the latest (tail) date (leave) on my Date Reporting and then sum the Customer Due Amount and get the result in a new measure called Due Amount.

When the users select a specific date, it does work, but when they select a week I get a #VALUE as result.

How should I create this correct?

Comment: How do you know it's the week level, not day? Hierarchy is MDX-based or SSRS-based?

Comment: As far as I know the first part ([Measures].[Due Amount],[Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].members) is what I have chosen as filter (week) (Sorry, newbie to MDX and calculations in a cube!). Not sure what you mean by Hierarchy is MDX-based or SSRS-based? Date Reporting is made in my multidim. cube with hierarchies (Year - Week - Date) and another (Year - Quarter - Month - Date). But this example only looks at the week in the Year - Week - Date hierarchy. Hope that answers your last question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, but can you show your report? Do you want to choose week and get the sum of  [Measures].[Due Amount] over the current week and last day of that week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my end result:

```
([Measures].[Due Amount],[Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week].members) =
SUM(TAIL(DESCENDANTS([Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].CURRENTMEMBER,
 [Date Reporting].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Date]),1)
,[Measures].[Customer Due Amount]);
```

This will do what I want:

Get the latest date in a selected week and sum the Customer Due Amounts and present it as Due Amount.